# different results in java and c# for right-shift operator

Tags: c#, java, operators

BHere's the code:

c#

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int a = -33554432;
  byte b = (byte)(a >> 24);
  MessageBox.Show(b.ToString());
}
```

java

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    int a = -33554432;
    byte b = (byte)(a >> 24);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Byte.toString(b));
}
```

I've read around this problem, and I believe there is a relatively simple way of understanding the different behavior, but I need a little help in reaching this understanding. Any takers, please?

Many thanks!

EDIT: ok, now using Byte.toString(). Output for c# = 254 java = -2

Comment: Curious, `Integer.toString()` on a byte in Java? Why not `Byte.toString()`?

Comment: You could also provide us an `output`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Byte in Java is a signed value. In this case you could actually just use:

```
// Note the triple >
int b = a >>> 24;
```

Alternatively:

```
byte b = (byte) (a >> 24);
int c = b & 0xff;
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, the alternative part is the answer. Will mark it as such in a minute. The >>> doesn't work (with code as specified), which was one of the reasons I asked here.

Comment: @ShunyataKharg: When you say ">>> doesn't work" - what happened when you tried? It should be fine.

Answer (score 6):

Java `byte` is signed so `>>` will fill in `1` bits from the left if the number is negative.

C# `byte` is unsigned so the `>>` operator is filling in `0` bits.

Either change `byte` to `sbyte` in your C# code or use `>>>` in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use in Java `>>>`. This does bit-shifting without taking care of the sign-bit.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no <<< operator.